# Windows platform, dynamic parallelism debugging is not supported in preemption mode

Tags: cuda, nsight

I already searched the relative solution to the DP debugging, but the situation seemed different from mine. I have only one GPU, GeForce GTX 750 Ti,  platform windows...So it's no need for me to configure the headless GPU, and I have forced the iterms "Desktop GPUs, Headless GPUs must use software preemption" to Faulse, and restart the system. When starting cuda debugging, "CUDA Dynamic Parallelism debugging is not supported in preemption mode. Breakpoints will be disabled" is prompted...How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might not be able to debug with one GPU. This is from two years ago from the [Nvidia developer's forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/536202/debugging-dynamic-parallelism-and-preemption-mode/):

> Nsight Visual Studio Edition single GPU debugging mode ("preemption
>   mode") is not yet supported for applications using CUDA Dynamic
>   Parallelism. Nsight VSE can debug CDP applications using remote
>   debugging or local debugging where the CDP capable device is headless
>   or configured to use the Tesla Compute Cluster (TCC) driver.

Comment: Thx for ans, I have seen that before. But I wonder questions: 1.Opeation system dependency? whether using single GPU to debug CDP also dose't work in Linux？  2. I think the reason that choosing to use headless GPU debugging is because the CUDA Debugger disables breakpoints automatically when attempting to debug locally on a GPU that has displays attached, which is also mentioned in Nsight VSE user guide. But the question is why only CDP is not supported, while other applications using CUDA debugging work well (the breakpoints work well)? They all use single GPU in my computer...